# Ray Box Intersection in C

Tags: c, intersection, raytracing, bounding-box

I am trying to make a method to calculate a ray box intersection in C. Most of the procedures I googled show methods that return bools (if there is or there isn't an intersection). However, I need a method that can return a tuple (I know there are no tuples in C, but I made a struct to represent it). Specifically, I need the values of tmin and tmax, even though they are negative, and assigning them a negative value if the value does not exist. How should I manage the returns of this to work properly? The code I produced in C is based on the code displayed in this page: https://tavianator.com/fast-branchless-raybounding-box-intersections-part-2-nans/. The actual implementation of the code in my program is as follows:

```
RectMinMax* Intersection(BoundingBox* b, Ray* r) {

RectMinMax* TMinMax = malloc(sizeof(RectMinMax));

float tmin = -INFINITY, tmax = INFINITY;

if (ray_get_direction(r).X != 0) {
  float t1 = (b->x - ray_get_origin(r).X) / ray_get_direction(r).X;
  float t2 = ((b->x + b->length) - ray_get_origin(r).X)/ ray_get_direction(r).X;

  tmin = fmaxf(tmin, fminf(t1, t2));
  tmax = fminf(tmax, fmaxf(t1, t2));
}

else if (ray_get_origin(r).X <= b->x || ray_get_origin(r).X >= (b->x + b->length)) {
  TMinMax->min = -55;
  TMinMax->max = -55;
  return TMinMax;
}

if (ray_get_direction(r).Y != 0) {
  float t1 = (b->y - ray_get_origin(r).Y) / ray_get_direction(r).Y;
  float t2 = ((b->y + b->width) - ray_get_origin(r).Y)/ ray_get_direction(r).Y;

  tmin = fmaxf(tmin, fminf(t1, t2));
  tmax = fminf(tmax, fmaxf(t1, t2));
}

else if (ray_get_origin(r).Y <= b->y || ray_get_origin(r).Y >= (b->y + b->width)) {
  TMinMax->min = -55;
  TMinMax->max = -55;
  return TMinMax;
}

if (ray_get_direction(r).Z != 0) {
  float t1 = (b->z - ray_get_origin(r).Z) / ray_get_direction(r).Z;
  float t2 = ((b->z + b->height) - ray_get_origin(r).Z)/ ray_get_direction(r).Z;

  tmin = fmaxf(tmin, fminf(t1, t2));
  tmax = fminf(tmax, fmaxf(t1, t2));
}

else if (ray_get_origin(r).Z <= b->z || ray_get_origin(r).Z >= (b->z + b->height)) {
  TMinMax->min = -55;
  TMinMax->max = -55;
  return TMinMax;
}

if (tmax > tmin && tmax > 0) {
  TMinMax->min = tmin;
  TMinMax->max = tmax;
  return TMinMax;
}
else {
  TMinMax->min = -55;
  TMinMax->max = -55;
  return TMinMax;
}
}
```

RectMinMax is just a struct with to attributes max and min. In the code I used -55 to represent the "return false" cases of the code in the link. I understand I am leaving out cases in which tmax is positive and tmin negative, for example, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: So what is your question? How to return multiple values from a C function?

Comment: No. I get how to return multiple values, I just dont understand how to modify the code to return the tmin and tmax when they are negative. I do not want bool false, but the actual values.

Comment: Add some extra fields to the structure to have all of the data you need.

Comment: "I understand I am leaving out cases in which tmax is positive and tmin negative"  Are you?  I don't think you are -- `if (tmax > tmin && tmax > 0)` properly handles `tmin < 0`.